# Phalcon, model bindings by field with json string or simple array string

Tags: phalcon

I want to hold array data (json data) in field "table_ids" of Table_2, eg:

**Table_1**

```
| id | name    |
----------------
| 1  | title 1 |
| 2  | title 2 | 
| 3  | title 3 |
| 4  | title 4 |
etc...
```

**Table_2**

```
| id | table_ids    |
---------------------
| 1  | "{1,3}"      | 
| 2  | "{3,4,2}"    |
```

And, I'm intrested how it's possible to make relation in Phalcon model of table 2, hasMany as "table1relation" to Table_1 by field "table_ids"

```
$this->hasMany( 'table_ids', 'Table1', 'id', array('alias' => 'table1relation' ));
```

so as result to have properly binded objects in Table_2

```
$tbl2 = Table2::find();
foreach( $id in $tbl2.table1relation ) {
    echo $id->name;
};
```

I'm wondering is this possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Ofcourse, binding like the one above not working, but I'm reading about custom behaviours on models http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-your-own-behaviors

Answer (score 0):

First working solution is this:

```
class Table2 extends Model
{

    ....

    // get all items with mapped Table1 model resulsets
    public static function GetItems() {

       $items = Table2::find()->filter( function( $current_item ){

        if ( $current_item->table_ids != null ) {

            $final = array();
            $array = explode( ",", $current_item->table_ids );

            foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
                $table1_item = Table1::findFirst($value);
                array_push( $final, $table1_item );
            }

            $current_item->table_ids = $final;
        } else {
            $current_item->table_ids = array();
        }
        return $current_item;
    });

    return $items;
    }

    public function beforeSave() {
        if ( is_array( $this->table_ids ) ){
            $cat_value = "";
            $ids = $this->table_ids;

            foreach( $ids as $ids_item ) {
                $cat_value .= $ids_item->id;
                if ( next( $ids ) == true ) $cat_value .= ",";
            }
            $this->table_ids = $cat_value;
        }
    }
}
```

And now we can use methods in controller like this

```
// get items
$items = Table2::GetItems();

foreach( $items->table_ids as $ids ) {
     echo $ids->name;
}

...

$ids = new Table1();
$ids->id = 6;
$ids->name = "title 6"

$item = new Table2();
$item->id = 10;
$item->table_ids = $ids;

// or

$item->table_ids = "1,2,3,4,5";
```

This work